# AggregateCursor issue with MongoDB 3.6

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregate-functions

I've updated my MongoDB to the **3.6** version. I'm using a PHP MongoClient on CentOS 7 and **PHP 5.5.38**. 
If I run the aggregateCursor method of the MongoDB library, through the first example reported in http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregatecursor.php, I obtain the following error message as below:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message '95.110.150.99:27017: the command cursor did not return a correctly structured response'
```

Do you have any idea about this behaviour?

Answer (score 8):

The problem was in the *cursor id* returned by Mongo:

```
 ["id"]=>
    float(6.43105103109E+18)
```

To build the *MongoCommandCursor* object, the *id* is expected to be a *MongoInt64*:

```
["id"]=>
    object(MongoInt64)#5 (1) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(12) "392143983421"
    }
```

It can be done by setting:

```
ini_set('mongo.native_long', false);
ini_set('mongo.long_as_object', true);
```

The problem is described in details at:
https://derickrethans.nl/64bit-ints-in-mongodb.html