# the command cursor did not return a correctly structured response

Tags: php, linux, mongodb

I updated my mongo from 2.6 to 4. I have got problem with aggregation query. I got the message : `the command cursor did not return a correctly structured response`.

As read in [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47578362/6410457), I put the configuration for

```
ini_set('mongo.native_long', false);
ini_set('mongo.long_as_object', true);
```

But now I got the error `Notice: Object of class MongoInt64 could not be converted to int`.

Does someone have an idea how to fix this?

Result of `php --ri mongodb`

```
php --ri mongodb

mongodb

MongoDB support => enabled
MongoDB extension version => 1.5.5
MongoDB extension stability => stable
libbson bundled version => 1.13.0
libmongoc bundled version => 1.13.0
libmongoc SSL => enabled
libmongoc SSL library => OpenSSL
libmongoc crypto => enabled
libmongoc crypto library => libcrypto
libmongoc crypto system profile => disabled
libmongoc SASL => disabled
libmongoc ICU => disabled
libmongoc compression => enabled
libmongoc compression snappy => disabled
libmongoc compression zlib => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mongodb.debug => no value => no value
```

Code which throws exception

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder();

        return $this->createAggregationBuilder()->match()
                ->field('delivery')->references($delivery)
                ->field('dateDeleted')->equals(null)$aggregation
                ->group()
                    ->field('id')
                    ->expression(null)
                    ->field('count')
                    ->sum(1)->execute()->getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Please share the code you are using, such that others can reproduce the problem

Comment: @NicoHaase aggregation doctrine added

Comment: MongoInt64 ? is it from the legacy driver?

Comment: Maybe but I need the two library.

Comment: @AlexBlex I unlink mongo extension but I got the same error.

Comment: You most definitely don't need the legacy driver. It's been deprecated for many years. The latest v1.6 supports wire protocol to the server up to v3.0 which itself reached end of life in September 2018: https://github.com/mongodb/docs-ecosystem/blob/9943a91f07fe96a3febc5ff4fde6949a1c62078d/source/includes/php-mongodb-compatibility-table.rst and https://www.mongodb.com/support-policy

Comment: If you still see "class MongoInt64" anywhere it is either - the legacy driver https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongoint64.php or a class defined in php code (a 3rd party library or your own application).

Comment: @AlexBlex I need the old driver since I have multiple project on same server.

Comment: I see. It's quite extreme setup. I guess you are running php5.6 then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210360/discussion-between-grenierj-and-alex-blex).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the `ini_options` it resolve the error of `the command cursor did not return a correctly structured response`. 
But since some data already exists in database, which was created by older Mongo driver, it can't fetch data.

So, I need to remove all my documents to restart with a clean database.